# Soft credits for workplace giving

Tags: civicontribute, soft-credit

(Civi 4.5.4, Drupal 7.17)

Has anyone out there in Stack Exchange-land utilized a workable solution (that doesn't require a tremendous amount of customization) for soft crediting workplace giving, e.g., Acme Supplies sends a check of $50,000 that incorporates donations of varying amounts from 100 employees, each of whom should be soft-credited in Civi.

Importing doesn't work because there's no option to specify the amount and what results is each soft credit being the amount of the total check.  While theoretically one could turn around the gift and hard-credit the employees while soft-crediting the organization (thus making the batch data entry form an option), that isn't really correct for tax purposes.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.